# Accessing the value in a System.Windows.Documents.TableCell

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, flowdocument, tablecell

I am trying to access the value of a TableCell from a FlowDocument and I'm completely stumped.

I am doing this within a unit test to assert one particular value (the date) made it into the document.

Here is the (ugly) code so far:

```
((Table) ((FlowDocument) actual.Source).Blocks.FirstBlock).RowGroups[0].Rows[0].Cells[1]
```

**Edit:**
At the point where this code is I cannot see how the value can be accessed.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete code sample, i.e your complete Unit Test, and the System Under Test you are testing?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide a complete code sample as it is proprietary information.  Though I don't see a reason why it would be needed as all I am asking is how to get the value of the TableCell Object the rest of the code has no bearing on that outcome.

Comment: Right. You are trying to get a particular value (a date) from a document and assert against that value I believe. Even it looks ugly, I cannot see another way of accessing a particular value.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit to hopefully clarify what I am looking for. The code in the question does not actually get the value, only a table cell object with no obviously apparent way to access it's value.